# Loading new window and populating form with a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What I would like to do is be able to press my extension button in the toolbar on a specific page which contains user data, when pressed it scrape the specified data, open a new window and load a URL, populate the form with the scraped data and submit the form.

So far I can scrape the data and open the new window, but I need some help populating the form and submitting.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js":      ["content.js"]
    }],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension"
    },

    "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.text && (msg.text == "report_back")) {
    var userdata = [];
    userdata[0] = document.getElementsByClassName("firstname").innerText;
    userdata[1] = document.getElementsByClassName("surname").innerText;
    userdata[3] = document.getElementsByClassName("dob").innerText;
    sendResponse(credentials);
    }
});
```

**background.js**

```
function domData(element) {
    alert("DOM content:\n" + element); // debug whats been sent

    chrome.windows.create({incognito: true, url: "http://admin.mysite.com/newuser.php"});
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { text: "report_back" },
                                domData);
});
```

**sample-scrape-page.html**

```
<span class="firstname">John</span>
<span class="surname">Doe</span>
<span class="dob">1st June 1990</span>
```

**newuser.php**

```
<form action="newuser.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="surname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="dob"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You're opening an incognito window but by default extensions are disabled in this mode unless a user manually enables the option. So you'll have to pass the values in the url as `&var=value` and this is not secure. If you're making a public extension that would be a deal breaker.

Comment: Yes I have selected the option to "Allow in Incognito". The extension will be for private use but passing them in the url is undesirable, surely there must be a way to pass data to new windows/tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a primitive untested solution with `activeTab` permission that doesn't inject a content script everywhere but uses [programmatic code injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) only when the toolbar button is pressed:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: "(" + (function() {
                ["firstname", "surname", "dob"].map(function(c) {
                    return document.getElementsByClassName(c).innerText;
                }).join("\n");
            }).toString() + ")()"
    }, function(result){
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            return;
        }
        chrome.windows.create({incognito: true, focused: true,
                url: "http://admin.mysite.com/newuser.php"}, function(window) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                code: "(" + (function(data) {
                        var data = data.split("\n");
                        ["firstname", "surname", "dob"].forEach(function(c, i) {
                            document.querySelector("input[name='"+c+"']").value = data[i];
                        });
                        document.forms[0].submit();
                    }).toString() + ")(" + result[0] + ")"
            }
        });
    });
});
```

An alternative better looking solution would be to inject a separate content script file using `file:` parameter instead of `code:` and use messaging.

Comment: Oops, indeed. Forgot that it's still global, not tab-specific.